# sending listdata of registered users from one application to other?

Tags: android, database

I am working on android project which has two application connected to same database in firebase. I want to show a list of registered users with their name and image of application A to  application B. I have seen some similar question on stackoverflow but they dont have solutions. If it is possible to do kindly give me solution.